# Optimize complex mysql query

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I have a database table which contains about 1.5 million records.
These records have latitude and longitude coordinates attached to them.

The goal is to return the record count, performing a xx mile radius search.
However, these records need to be checked against another table, and if the unique id exists in the other table, that record needs to be removed from the count.

I considered adding a field to the record that marks it unavailable, but they want to use a master exclusion list.

How can I trim the overhead and speed this query up?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM (
                        SELECT unique_id, lat,lon,(((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) 
                        * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos((($lon- `Lon`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as 
                        distance FROM records WHERE unique_id NOT IN (SELECT unique_id from records_suppressed)) 
                    as result WHERE distance <= ".$miles.";"
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: Pls add the result of explain and the create tables of all underlying tales to the question!

Comment: Not quite sure how to add the explain.
Here is the db structure

http://i65.tinypic.com/99i4qp.jpg

Comment: 1  PRIMARY  records  index  NULL Radius Search  175  NULL 1541608  Using where; Using index

3  MATERIALIZED  records_suppressed  index  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  167  NULL 4126  Using index

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT r.unique_id
     , r.lat
     , r.lon
     , (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180))
        * sin((`r.lat`*pi()/180))
        + cos(($lat*pi()/180)) 
        * cos((`r.lat`*pi()/180)) 
        * cos((($lon - `r.lon`)*pi()/180))))
        * 180/pi())*60*1.1515) distance 
     FROM records r
     LEFT 
     JOIN records_suppressed s
       ON s.unique_id = r.unique_id
    WHERE (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180))
        * sin((`r.lat`*pi()/180))
        + cos(($lat*pi()/180)) 
        * cos((`r.lat`*pi()/180)) 
        * cos((($lon - `r.lon`)*pi()/180))))
        * 180/pi())*60*1.1515) <= $miles
      AND s.unique_id IS NULL;
```

Further, you can add a range limit equivalent to a bounding rectangle centered on the given location and of sides equal to the diameter of the circle.

Comment: Cannot get the query to work as written. Complains of ambigious unique_id however records.unique_id complains not in field list.

Comment: I was successfully able to drop the suppressed record search and cut the time in half with the remaining code from above.

Now if I can get the left join to work ...
-----

Comment: Edited to remove ambiguities